# oracle in between date not working

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from table where EMPNO='123'  
and TO_DATE('08-Dec-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') between  EFF_FROM_DATE  and EFF_TO_DATE ;
```

I have two rows with data :

```
EFF_FROM_DATE            EFF_TO_DATE 
25-OCT-2015 15:45:19    08-DEC-2015 09:22:17
08-DEC-2015 09:22:17    31-DEC-9999 00:00:00
```

but this query is fetching data only for -

> 25-OCT-2015 15:45:19  08-DEC-2015 09:22:17

what am I doing wrong in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably intend this:

```
select *
from table
where EMPNO = '123' and 
      DATE '2015-12-08' >= trunc(EFF_FROM_DATE) and
      DATE '2015-12-08' < trunc(EFF_TO_DATE) + interval '1' day;
```

The problem is that the time component affects the comparison.  The "from" date has a time component, so `date '2015-12-08'` is less than `'2015-12-08 10:09:22'`.  Hence the original logic doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need trunc column EFF_FROM_DATE  and EFF_TO_DATE. something like this:

```
select * from table where EMPNO='123'  
and TO_DATE('08-Dec-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') between  TRUNC(EFF_FROM_DATE)  and (EFF_TO_DATE);
```